# Cardinality of real-valued set with unique pairwise sums

Tags: set-theory

Consider the real-valued equivalent of a [Sidon set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence), i.e., a set $\mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that all pair-wise sums of elements are different:

\begin{equation}
\forall x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\in\mathcal{X},\quad \{x_1, x_2\}\ne\{x_3, x_4\} \implies x_1+x_2\ne x_3+x_4
\tag{1}
\label{eq:rsidon}
\end{equation}

Note that $x_1=x_2$ is possible, i.e., relations of the form $x_1+x_1=x_3+x_4$ with $x_4\ne x_1\ne x_3$ are also not allowed. Let us call this a *real-valued Sidon set*.

There are algorithms to design standard (integer-valued) Sidon sets, which are also real-valued Sidon sets and are countably infinite. I am interested to know whether there exists a real-valued Sidon set that is uncountable.

Intuitively I believe it should exist. Any set $\mathcal{X}$ of cardinality $|\mathcal{X}|$ satisfying \eqref{eq:rsidon} can be extended by adding a new element $x_0\notin \mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{S}=\left\{x_1+x_2-x_3\colon x_1, x_2, x_3\in\mathcal{X}\right\}$. The cardinality of the set $\mathcal{S}$ of "forbidden" elements is $|\mathcal{S}|=\frac{|\mathcal{X}|^2(|\mathcal{X}|+1)}{2}$ (because swapping $x_1$ and $x_2$ produces the same element). This means that the set $\mathbb{R}-\mathcal{S}$ of elements that can be added to $\mathcal{X}$ is uncountable if $\mathcal{X}$ is countable. However, this is just an intuition and not a proof.

Question: **is there a proof (or even better, an example) of the (non-)existence of an uncountable set $\mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies \eqref{eq:rsidon}?**

Comment: It seems to me that your intuition is one instance of Zorn lemma close to a proof in ZFC that there is a real-valued Sidon set with cardinality continuum, isn't it?

Comment: Offhand I'd guess that there is a nonempty perfect set of real numbers satisfying (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this paper answers the question, as Golomb rulers and Sidon sets are equivalent:

https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.0933v1